# ¿Como modificar este bucle para que no se pongan todos de azul?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Quiero que cada vez que se pulse click en el `< p class = categoria>` se ponga de color azul.

```
 <section>
   <div class="first_section">
      <div class="first_subsection">
          <div id="london" class="first_minidiv">
             <p class="categoria">Diversion en familia</p>
             <div class="minidiv_desc">
                <h4>Londres <br/>44€</h4>
                <p class="noches">8 noches</p>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div id="paris" class="first_minidiv">
             <p class="categoria">Eventos</p>
             <div class="minidiv_desc">
                <h4>Paris <br/>42€</h4>
                <p class="noches">8 noches</p>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div id="lisboa" class="first_minidiv">
             <p class="categoria">Turismo y cultura</p>
             <div class="minidiv_desc">
                <h4>Lisboa <br/>81€</h4>
                <p class="noches">8 noches</p>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Para eso he hecho esto pero me da error:

```
var categoria = document.querySelectorAll("p.categoria");


function cambiaelcolor(){
    categoria.style.color = "blue";
}

for (var i = 0 ; i < categoria.length; i++) {
    categoria[i].addEventListener('click' , cambiaelcolor , false ) ; 
 }
```

Así que intentando solucionar añadí también un bucle en la función de cambiar color:

```
 var categoria = document.querySelectorAll("p.categoria");


function cambiaelcolor(){
    for (var i = 0 ; i < categoria.length; i++) {
        categoria[i].style.color = "blue"; 
     }
}

for (var i = 0 ; i < categoria.length; i++) {
    categoria[i].addEventListener('click' , cambiaelcolor , false ) ; 
 }
```

Ahora funciona pero mal, porque cada vez que pincho en uno se ponen todos de azul. ¿Que es lo que hay que modificar para que se ponga de azul SÓLO el que se pincha?

Comment: Se ponen todos en azul porque así se lo dices en el bucle, vas uno a uno cambiando el color ¿que esperabas que hiciera el bucle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
var categoria = document.querySelectorAll("p.categoria");


function cambiaelcolor(){
  this.style.color = "blue"; 
}

for (var i = 0 ; i < categoria.length; i++) {
    categoria[i].addEventListener('click' , cambiaelcolor , false ) ; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="first_section">
  <div class="first_subsection">             
    <div id="london" class="first_minidiv">
      <p class="categoria">Diversion en familia</p>
      <div class="minidiv_desc">
        <h4>Londres <br/>44€</h4>
        <p class="noches">8 noches</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="paris" class="first_minidiv">
      <p class="categoria">Eventos</p>
      <div class="minidiv_desc">
        <h4>Paris <br/>42€</h4>
          <p class="noches">8 noches</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lisboa" class="first_minidiv">
      <p class="categoria">Turismo y cultura</p>
      <div class="minidiv_desc">
        <h4>Lisboa <br/>81€</h4>
        <p class="noches">8 noches</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Tienes la función `cambiaelcolor()` mal planteada. Al hacer un bucle que recorra todos los elementos estás asignando el cambio de color a todos y cada uno de los `<p>` que sean de la clase `.categoria`.

En programación existe el concepto del `this`, que depende del ámbito hace referencia a una o a otra cosa. En el caso de los eventos hace referencia al **elemento** que tiene el evento asignado y que se dispara junto con este. Es justo lo que necesitamos puesto que así podremos saber cual de los eventos `onclick` se ha disparado y de esta manera poder afectar tan solo al que se le haya hecho "click".